# fusion of different resolution satellite image?

Tags: classification, image

I have two dataset

1. Worldview (38cm: pansharpened) - R,G,B
2. Planetscope (3m) - R,G,B,NIR

But, worldview image has only R,G,B, so I can't figure out spectral response for classification.
I think it's not pansharpening, but is any method to combine them with high resolution like worldview with NIR reflectance?

Comment: Why are you using two different datasets? What do you hope to accomplish with the fusion?

Comment: Not really "fusion" there, but a simple approach could be to just disaggregrate the NIR band of Planetscope to the resolution of Worldview and deal with the fact that it's slightly incorrect.

Comment: As the last post says, I want to apply NIR from planetscope to Worldview to improve classification.